# Rails: Model attributes from XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am new to Rails and would like your suggestions for the following.

I have a model say Video.
Certain attributes of the Video are stored in MySQL database while some of other attributes are stored in an associated XML file on the server.

For example, `id`, `title` and `slug` is stored in the database while `duration`, `thumbnails`, `description`, etc are stored in an XML file.

How should I implement my model so that I can access all the attributes of the video and not only those stored in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `after_find` or `after_initialize` to read the attributes from the file and populate some virtual attributes in your object.  Then use the `after_save` to check if the attributes have changed and if so write the new ones back out to the file.  [More detail in the ActiveRecord::Callbacks docs, here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)